# We have three points A,B,C and angle θ. how to draw a circle that crosses B and C and its angle to point A equals θ?

Tags: geometry

In the name of God
We have three points A,B,C and angle θ. how to draw a circle that crosses B and C and its angle to point A equals θ?
I don't even understand what the question means by saying "the circle's angle to point A is equal to θ".

But I think it means: If we draw two tangent line from point A to the circle, the angle between tangent lines should be equal to θ:
[image: picture 1]

I think this question has no answer in certain Conditions. I mean there is no circle that we can draw if A is too close to BC and θ is too small or something like that.
I've no idea to solve this question. any suggestions?

Comment: Take care not to be mislead by your figure : line segment $AB$ hasn't to be a diameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three key points.

- 1. The center of such a circle, if it exists, is on the bissector line $(L)$ of line segment $BC$.
- 2. The locus of points "seeing" a certain circle with radius $R$ under angle $\theta$ (as in your figure) is a concentric circle of the first one with radius $R'$ such that $\frac{R}{R'}=\sin \tfrac{\theta}{2}$ (easily verified by reasoning on a certain right triangle).
- 3. The locus of points $M$ having a given ratio of distances $\rho:=\frac{MB}{MA}=\frac{R}{R'}$ to 2 fixed points $A$ and $B$ is a circle $\Gamma$ belonging to the family of **circles of Apollonius** defined by $A$ and $B$ (see blue circles on this [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles)); see as well [there](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/LocusCircle.shtml#solution). *This circle $\Gamma$ can be constructed in the following way : its center is on line $AB$ ; the two  points $m_1,m_2$ on line $AB$ such $\rho:=\frac{m_kA}{m_kB}$ are the endpoints of a diameter.*

Therefore, due to point 1), the center $M$ of the looked-for circle is at the intersection of bissector line $(L)$ and circle of Apollonius $\Gamma$ *if such an intersection exists*.

Please note that there are potentialy two solutions.

Comment: thanks for the answer.